# Dictionary only captures last key value pair Python

Tags: python, dictionary

There is a dictionary for names and a function to print the dictionary. The problem is when I run the create_user() function it only captures and prints the last values.

```
users={}

def create_users():

    while True:
        choice=input('Create a new user?: Y/N ')
        if(choice=='y'):
           first_name=  input('Enter first name: ')
           users['first_name'] = first_name

           last_name= input('Enter last name: ')
           users['last_name']=last_name

           print(len(users))

        if(choice=='n'):
            print('Exit')
            break

def print_dir():
    print('Directory Item ','\n')
    for k,v in users.items():
        print(k,v)

create_users()
print_dir()
```

I have also tried this below, capturing before while and after while. That did not solve.

```
def create_user():
  first_name=  input('Enter first name: ')
  users['first_name'] = first_name

  last_name= input('Enter last name: ')
  users['last_name']=last_name

  while True:
        choice=input('Create a new user?: Y/N ')
        if(choice=='y'):
           first_name=  input('Enter first name: ')
           users['first_name'] = first_name

           last_name= input('Enter last name: ')
           users['last_name']=last_name
```

Any hint/clue  how can I solve this? Thanks

Additional Item I tried per suggestion (nested dictionary)

```
users={}
users['username'] = {}

while True:
        choice=input('Create a new user?: Y/N ')
        if(choice=='y'):
           first_name=  input('Enter first name: ')
           users['username']['first_name'] = first_name

           last_name= input('Enter last name: ')
           users['username']['last_name']=last_name
```

I still had the same issue of not getting all the values
Create a new user?: Y/N y

Enter first name: james

Enter last name: jones

Create a new user?: Y/N y

Enter first name: rob

Enter last name: william

Create a new user?: Y/N n

Exit
Directory Item

username {'first_name': 'rob', 'last_name': 'william'}

Comment: [mcve] with example input / expected output please.

Comment: You are basically creating a dictionary with just two key that is 'first_name' and 'last_name' and also each time you input a value in first_name or last_name, these keys are been overwritten by first_name and last_name variables. That's why you the dictionary is containing the last value for each of the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary is a key-value pair.Dictionary has unique keys. So when you run the program, and choose second-time 'y' it will update the existing key which is 'first_name' and 'last_name'. You **cannot have data in dictionary** like {'first_name':'A','last_name':'B','first_name':'C','last_name':'D'} in this case the keys are repeated.  However, you can save first_name as key and last name as values. see the below code.

```
users={}

def create_users():

    while True:
        choice=input('Create a new user?: Y/N ')
        if(choice=='y'):
           first_name=  input('Enter first name: ')
           # users['first_name'] = first_name

           last_name= input('Enter last name: ')
           # users['last_name']=last_name
           users[first_name] = last_name
           print(len(users))

        if(choice=='n'):
            print('Exit')
            break

def print_dir():
    print('Directory Item ','\n')
    for k,v in users.items():
        print(k,v)

create_users()
print_dir()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It does make sense that why firstname,lastname part will not work. I accepted the answer, however if I wanted to  use fname,lname let's say a user wants to know what is the fname, how can I design it?

Comment: I think is you want to use fname, lname you can keep 'users' as list. and keep each user as dictionary so final structure will be something [{fname:fname1,lname:lname1},{fname:fname2,lname:lname2}]. Rest depends upon how you design it. So add each student with list.append() operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
users['last_name']=last_name
```

Your problem is that users is being used to store a single user's data. What you want is something more like

```
users[username]['last_name']=last_name
```

Making users a dictionary of dictionaries. Where to get username is up to you. If you don't have a good source, making users into a list of dictionaries may be better.